# Chained docker image start httpd and php

Tags: dockerfile, centos8

I've got 2 Docker containers: httpd-container and php-container.

httpd-container dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:latest

RUN yum -y install httpd

RUN sed -i 's/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride all/g' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

php-container dockerfile

```
FROM httpd-container:latest

RUN yum -y install php php-cli php-fpm php-mysqlnd php-zip php-devel php-gd php-mbstring php-curl php-xml php-pear php-bcmath php-json

RUN mkdir /run/php-fpm

CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Currently I have to run `/usr/sbin/php-fpm` in php-container after it starts.
I`ve have tried putting both commands in one script and setting that as entry point, but it does not find it.
I've tried running supervisord and got errors as well.

Any advice is deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Change php-container dockerfile to

```
FROM httpd-container:latest

RUN yum -y install php php-cli php-fpm php-mysqlnd php-zip php-devel php-gd php-mbstring php-curl php-xml php-pear php-bcmath php-json

RUN mkdir /run/php-fpm

COPY ./start_services.sh /

CMD ["/start_services.sh"]
```

create start_services.sh with

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/sbin/php-fpm

/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```